# Why does a semaphore in a Linux C language program cause SIGABRT Aborted?

Tags: c, linux

My development environment is CentOS 7.9-x86_64 and the compiler is using gcc11.

```
[root@dev src]# uname -a
Linux dev 3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 8 19:51:47 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@dev src]# 
[root@dev src]# 
[root@dev src]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
[root@dev src]# 
[root@dev src]# 
[root@dev src]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9)
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
[root@dev src]#
```

Below is my code snippet:

1. This is a header file that defines a structure EuclidCommand, and this structure contains a semaphore.

```
#include <semaphore.h>

typedef struct euclid_command
{
    char *bytes;
    char *result;
    sem_t sem;
} EuclidCommand;
```

2. The following is the program logic part.

```
/**
* Allocate a piece of memory for the structure object EuclidCommand, and allocate 
* an additional 4 bytes as additional information for this structure object.
*/
int hidden = 4;
void *obj_head = malloc(hidden + sizeof(EuclidCommand));
memset(obj_head, 0, hidden + sizeof(EuclidCommand));
EuclidCommand *task = obj_head + hidden;
task->bytes = buf;

sem_init(&(task->sem), 0, 0);

/**
* Submit the task object to another thread for processing, that thread will increment 
* the value of the semaphore by 1 after execution is complete.
*/
submit_command(task);

sem_wait(&(task->sem));
sem_destroy(&(task->sem));

// do something
```

The above code can be executed correctly.
Next, I made a small change, I changed the number of bytes of that additional memory from 4 to 2.

```
/**
* Allocate a piece of memory for the structure object EuclidCommand, and allocate 
* an additional 2 bytes as additional information for this structure object.
*/
int hidden = 2;
void *obj_head = malloc(hidden + sizeof(EuclidCommand));
memset(obj_head, 0, hidden + sizeof(EuclidCommand));
EuclidCommand *task = obj_head + hidden;
```

Execute the program again after recompiling the code. When the 'sem_wait(&(task->sem));' line of code is executed, the program fails. Use gdb to view the program stack at that time as shown in the following figure:
[image]

I guess the cause of this problem is related to byte alignment, but I am not sure of the real cause of this problem. I hope to meet friends who are familiar with Linux C language development to help me answer.

thank you very much

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `EuclidCommand *task = obj_head + hidden;`? You're offsetting the start of a `EuclidCommand` by `hidden` bytes. This might completely break alignment of members. Also, arithmetic with `void *` is a compiler extension and is not standard.

Comment: If you want to add some extra bytes to your allocation, you can add them after the end of the struct you are using. You can use a flexible array member for that purpose. But just moving around a pointer without taking care about alignment won't fly.

Comment: Every data type in C has some minimum required alignment.  `malloc` guarantees that the pointer it returns will be sufficiently aligned to satisfy any such alignment requirement.  Adding 2 (or 4) to such a pointer violates that guarantee, just as you've seen.

Comment: Thank you all, I have solved the problem, it is indeed caused by broken byte alignment, but I have to hide some meta information on the allocated memory, so I adjusted the number of hidden bytes to 8, which guarantees Bytes are always aligned.